# How to customize iPad keyboard appearance from the right side of the screen?

Tags: ios, ipad, keyboard, uitextfield

I made a custom keyboard using UITextField method inputView. That works perfectly. But the keyboard shows as a normal keyboard from the bottom of the screen. I would like to animate the  keyboard appearance from the right side of the screen.
Is that even possible ?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: There is no API to customize how the standard keyboard appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with coding my own keyboard.

If somebody is interested:

```
@interface Keyboard ()

@property (assign, readwrite) BOOL visible;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *editingTextInput;

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *blockingView;

@end


@implementation Keyboard

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self addObservers];
        self.exclusiveTouch = YES;
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self addObservers];
        self.exclusiveTouch = YES;
    }
    return self;
}


#pragma mark Register for notifications

- (void)addObservers {
    // Keep track of the textView/Field that we are editing
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(editingDidBegin:)
                                                 name:UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification
                                               object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(editingDidBegin:)
                                                 name:UITextViewTextDidBeginEditingNotification
                                               object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(editingDidEnd:)
                                                 name:UITextFieldTextDidEndEditingNotification
                                               object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(editingDidEnd:)
                                                 name:UITextViewTextDidEndEditingNotification
                                               object:nil];


}

- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification
                                                  object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:UITextViewTextDidBeginEditingNotification
                                                  object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:UITextFieldTextDidEndEditingNotification
                                                  object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:UITextViewTextDidEndEditingNotification
                                                  object:nil];

}

-(BOOL)isKeyboardForTextField:(UITextField*)textField
{
    // need to be implemented at child object
    return NO;
}



#pragma mark Show In View

static UIView *showInView;
+(void)setShowInView:(UIView *)view {
    showInView = view;
}
+(UIView*)showInView {
    return showInView;
}


#pragma mark Notifications  - editing DidBegin/End

// Editing just began, store a reference to the object that just became the firstResponder
- (void)editingDidBegin:(NSNotification *)notification {
    if ([notification.object isKindOfClass:[UIResponder class]])
    {
        if ([notification.object conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInput)]) {
            if([self isKeyboardForTextField:notification.object]) {
                [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(hideKeyboard) object:nil];
                _targetTextInput = notification.object;
                _targetTextInput.inputView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectNull];;

                if(!_visible) {
                    [self showKeyboard];
                }
            }

            return;
        }
    }

    // Not a valid target for us to worry about.
    _targetTextInput = nil;
}

// Editing just ended.
- (void)editingDidEnd:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [self performSelector:@selector(hideKeyboard) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1]; // so we have chance to stop it
}


#pragma mark Show / Hide keyboard


-(void)enableUserInteraction {
    [_blockingView removeFromSuperview];
}

-(void)disableUserInteraction {
    _blockingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[Keyboard showInView].frame];
    _blockingView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [[Keyboard showInView] addSubview:_blockingView];
}

- (void)showKeyboardWithAnimation:(BOOL)animation
{
    [[Keyboard showInView] addSubview:self];

    _visible = NO;
    [self disableUserInteraction];

    if (IS_IPHONE)
    {
        [self setOrigin:CGPointMake(0, [Keyboard showInView].size.height)];
        [self updateBackground];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:( animation ? .2 : 0)
                              delay:0.0
                            options: UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                         animations:^(void){
                             [self moveOriginY:-self.size.height];
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             _visible = YES;
                             [self enableUserInteraction];
                         }];

    } else {
        [self setOrigin:CGPointMake([Keyboard showInView].size.width, [Keyboard showInView].size.height - self.size.height - 10)];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:( animation ? .5 : 0)
                              delay:0.0
                            options: UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                         animations:^(void){
                             [self moveOriginX:-self.size.width];
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             _visible = YES;
                             [self enableUserInteraction];

                         }];
    }


}


-(void)showKeyboard
{
    [self showKeyboardWithAnimation:YES];
}

- (void)hideKeyboardWithAnimation:(BOOL)animation
{
    [self disableUserInteraction];

    if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:( animation ? .2 : 0)
                              delay:0.0
                            options: UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                         animations:^(void){
                             [self moveOriginY:self.size.height];

                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             [self removeFromSuperview];
                             _visible = NO;
                             [self enableUserInteraction];

                         }];

    } else {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:( animation ? .5 : 0)
                              delay:0.0
                            options: UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                         animations:^(void){
                             [self moveOriginX:self.size.width];

                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             [self removeFromSuperview];
                             _visible = NO;
                             [self enableUserInteraction];
                         }];
    }

}

-(void)hideKeyboard
{
    [self hideKeyboardWithAnimation:YES];
}

@end
```

UIView categories:

```
@implementation UIView (Frame)

-(CGPoint)origin {
    return self.frame.origin;
}

-(CGSize)size {
    return self.frame.size;
}


#pragma mark Change Origin

-(void)setOrigin:(CGPoint)origin
{
    CGRect frame = self.frame;
    frame.origin = origin;
    self.frame = frame;
}


-(void)setOriginX:(CGFloat)x
{
    CGRect frame = self.frame;
    frame.origin.x = x;
    self.frame = frame;
}

-(void)setOriginY:(CGFloat)y
{
    CGRect frame = self.frame;
    frame.origin.y = y;
    self.frame = frame;
}


#pragma mark Move Origin

-(void)moveOrigin:(CGPoint)origin
{
    CGRect frame = self.frame;
    frame.origin.y += origin.y;
    frame.origin.x += origin.x;
    self.frame = frame;
}


-(void)moveOriginX:(CGFloat)x
{
    CGRect frame = self.frame;
    frame.origin.x += x;
    self.frame = frame;
}

-(void)moveOriginY:(CGFloat)y
{
    CGRect frame = self.frame;
    frame.origin.y += y;
    self.frame = frame;
}




#pragma mark Change Size

-(void)setSize:(CGSize)size
{
    CGRect frame = self.frame;
    frame.size = size;
    self.frame = frame;
}

-(void)setSizeWidth:(CGFloat)width
{
    CGRect frame = self.frame;
    frame.size.width = width;
    self.frame = frame;
}

-(void)setSizeHeight:(CGFloat)height
{
    CGRect frame = self.frame;
    frame.size.height = height;
    self.frame = frame;
}

#pragma mark Change Size


-(void)addSizeWidth:(CGFloat)width
{
    CGRect frame = self.frame;
    frame.size.width += width;
    self.frame = frame;
}

-(void)addSizeHeight:(CGFloat)height
{
    CGRect frame = self.frame;
    frame.size.height += height;
    self.frame = frame;
}
@end
```